Ledger error: Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'USB': No device selected
Getting this error while trying to withdraw rewards from https://staking.polkadot.cloud/#/pools
Note that I don't see any metadata updates at https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/settings/metadata that are normally required to fix signing issues.

Any idea how to fix this issue?
Note that the ledger in unlocked and connected and polkadot app is opened.
